# Priority Queue poll() time complexity

Tags: java, queue, time-complexity, big-o, priority-queue

Given the code below:

```
pq.offer(x);
pq.poll();
```

For the first line code, element x is inserted into Priority Queue pq, the time complexity of the `offer` is log(k), where k is the size of pq.

Then my question is, for the second line code that immediately follows the first line, what'll be the time complexity for `poll()` ?

After first line `offer`, the pq has already been sorted, so `poll` will simply retrieve and remove the head of queue, then I think it should be O(1), correct?

Thanks

Comment: Items in a Java `PriorityQueue` are not sorted. Items are inserted into a [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap), which is an ordered, but not necessarily stored, data structure.

Comment: @JimMischel - they are stored all right. Just not sorted.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Thanks. Looks like last night I was CEO of typos-r-us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the source code of `PriorityQueue#poll`, it seems that the operation is `O(log n)`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public E poll() {
    if (size == 0)
        return null;
    int s = --size;
    modCount++;
    E result = (E) queue[0];
    E x = (E) queue[s];
    queue[s] = null;
    if (s != 0)
        siftDown(0, x);
    return result;
}
```

This is because `siftDown` is `O(log n)`, due to the data within the `PriorityQueue` being stored as a heap.

Comment: Thanks so much! Yeah I just read the source code and u r correct.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to and removing from a heap-based PQ are both *O(log(N))*.

This is stated clearly in the Javadoc.